# How to shake the inner text of a DIV tag without shaking the DIV

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

I'm creating a chess game and I want to show an `invalid movement` animation when the user makes an invalid move. My tiles are `HTML Div Elements` that contain text. I have the following `@keyframes`:

```
@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

But when I apply the animation to the `HTML DIV Element` the entire square shakes. I just want the inner text to shake, not the `Div Element` itself. How can I apply the `@keyframes` only to the inner text?

Edit:
HTML Markup for the row containing the white pawns

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">p</div>
      <div class="col">p</div>
      <div class="col">p</div>
      <div class="col">p</div>
      <div class="col">p</div>
      <div class="col">p</div>
      <div class="col">p</div>
      <div class="col">p</div>
   </div>
```

I just want the `p` to shake. Not the `DIV` containing that `p`.
You can see my game in my GitHub: https://github.com/carlos-dubon/chess

Comment: add your `HTML markup` structure also.

Comment: Can you include the HTML that this applies to also please? We can't help you fix the problem if we can't see what it is :) Please see how to create a [MRE]

Comment: Wrap the text in another div and apply the animation to that.

Comment: @jinongun done :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten sure :)

Comment: @rayhatfield maybe, but that's a lot of work. Any CSS way to do this?

Comment: Use `text-indent` instead of `transform`?

Comment: @rayhatfield that worked :D thank you!